# Ubuntu install - 'Try Ubuntu' freezes screen

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu 14.04. First I chose the option 'Try Ubuntu' to make sure everything was working properly. However the screen freezes with a dark background and the following sentences:

- Starting Mount network filesystem [ OK ]
- Stopping Mount network filesystem [ OK ]

But it doesn't go anywhere else. What should I do?